# MySQL auto_increment initial value

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I created a table in MySQL V5.7.28 where the PKs initial value is 50 and increases in steps of 10. e.g. 50, 60, 70 etc. My code is :

```
  Set Session auto_increment_increment=10;

  Create Table Dept (
  DeptNo Integer NOT NULL auto_increment,  
  DName Varchar(45), 
  Primary Key (DeptNo)
  ) AUTO_INCREMENT=50;
```

I inserted 3 rows into the table, and get

```
  51, Accounting
  61, Sales
  71, Tax
```

The increment size is correct (10) but the initial value is 1 higher than I expected.

If I open another session, rerun the above code without the "**Set Session auto_increment_increment=10;**" I get what is expected

```
  50, Accounting
  51, Sales
  52, Tax
```

which is the correct initial value of 50, but the step size is 1 rather than the 10 I which I was planning on using.

Setting the auto_increment_increment seems to increase the initial value of auto_increment field by 1.

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?
Many Thanks,

Comment: Auto increment columns start by default with 1. this has the big advantage that you will never have a row with Id=0 and so no possible complications by requesting row with Id=null or you can insert with with Id=null and the database will automatically use the next Auto increment value.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the values to be multiples of 10, you can `set auto_increment_offset=10;`

Demo:

```
mysql> create table mytable (id int auto_increment primary key);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> set auto_increment_increment=10;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> set auto_increment_offset=10;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into mytable () values ();
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> insert into mytable () values ();
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> insert into mytable () values ();
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> select * from mytable;
+----+
| id |
+----+
| 10 |
| 20 |
| 30 |
+----+
```

You can't set the offset to 0, because the minimum value is 1.

```
mysql> set auto_increment_offset=0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                              |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect auto_increment_offset value: '0' |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

It is unwise to expect anything other than 'uniqueness' from `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

There are many cases where a number will be skipped without really letting you know.

If different connections are inserting into that table, they need proper coordination.

Etc.

Instead of using A_I, consider something like

```
INSERT INTO Dept (...)
    SELECT MAX(DeptNo) + 10, "PartyPlanning"
        FROM Dept;
```